# PHP regex for checking if it contains any sql

Tags: php, sql, preg-match

How can I use PHP preg_match for a string to check if it contains any sql? Not for preventing SQL injection but just to tell if it contains a sql statement

Comment: You can't. You can look for some SQL specific keywords, but to check if its valid SQL you need some heavier logic.

Comment: You could try to execute the query and get the return of that execute in a variable. You could set up a test database for these queries so your actual data isn't compromised.

Comment: `$sql = 's' . 'e' . 'l' . 'e' . 'c' . 't' . 'etc...'`. There's a string that contains some SQL...good luck coming up with a regex that could detect every potential variation of that...

Answer (score 3):

Checking a string for SQL is not worth your time or resources for that matter. If the goal is to prevent injection you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Reference material: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)